# Remmina can't connect to university PC

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

My university offers remote connection to Library PCs. [Here is a list](https://remoteaccess.labstats.com/Swansea-University) of RDP files they offer. The RDP files works seamlessly with Windows 10. But in Ubuntu LTS 20.04, it does not work.

Here, I enter my credentials and domain(although not required).
[image]

Then it says,

[image]

I don't know what the issue is. Please don't ask me to use VNC or ssh. Nor ask me to change router settings. These PCs are in my University library.

Comment: Have you asked Swansea University's support service? That should be one of your starting points

Comment: Yes, they said RDP is proprietary. They don't think anyone can replicate the complex RDP configuration without the source code.

Comment: If you look at the error message, it says `Check "Security protocol negotiation"` which indicates that the protocol of Remmina that you are using can't negotiate with what the university is using. You need to go into Remmina's settings and choose either the protocol that the university is using if you know it or either `Automatic negotiation` or else use different software. If that doesn't work and you can't get help from their support, then no one here can help you because we don't maintain their infrastructure.

Comment: According to the link you have provided, the target RDP systems require MFA. Based on [this Github issue](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2096), Remmina doesn't support MFA yet.

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes, I tried every single security negotiation. It didn't work

Comment: @Haxiel Yes, I have MFA setup using Microsoft authenticator. Is there any Linux RDP software that supports MFA? Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Rather than waiting for someone to respond, you'll find out more quickly by using Google.

Comment: I can't find an RDP client that supports MFA for Ubuntu.